# Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line! in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gdb, spacemacs

I need to run gdb inside Docker, and I have a strong preference for the interface provided by emacs.

When doing M-x gdb, I enter "docker-compose -f ~/docker-services/dev/docker-compose.yml exec dev_rhel7 bash -c "gdb -i=mi"", and then it shows me the following message.

> Current directory is /home/drcoeurjoly/docker-services/dev/
>
> Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line!
>   WARNING: The MY_UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>
> 1-inferior-tty-set /dev/pts/3
>
> 2-gdb-set height 0
>
> 3-gdb-set non-stop 1
>
> 4-enable-pretty-printing
>
> 5-file-list-exec-source-files
>
> 6-file-list-exec-source-file
>
> 7-gdb-show prompt
>
> 8-stack-info-frame
>
> 9-thread-info
>
> 10-break-list
>
> 11-thread-info
>
> 12-break-list
>
> =thread-group-added,id="i1"
>
> ~"GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-114.el7\n"
>
> ~"Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
>
> ~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
>
> ~"This GDB was configured as \"x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu\".\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
>
> ~"http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.\n"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="history save",value="on"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="history filename",value="/home/drcoeurjoly/dotfiles/gdb/.gdb_history"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="print pretty",value="on"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="print object",value="on"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="print vtbl",value="on"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="demangle-style",value="gnu-v3"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="follow-fork-mode",value="child"
>
> =cmd-param-changed,param="detach-on-fork",value="off"
>
> (gdb)
>
> 1^done
>
> (gdb)
>
> 2^done
>
> (gdb)
>
> 3^done
>
> (gdb)
>
> 4^done
>
> (gdb)
>
> 5^done,files=[]
>
> (gdb)
>
> 6^error,msg="No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command."
>
> (gdb)
>
> 7^done,value="(gdb) "
>
> (gdb)
>
> 8^error,msg="No registers."
>
> (gdb)
>
> 9^done,threads=[]
>
> (gdb)
>
> 10^done,BreakpointTable={nr_rows="0",nr_cols="6",hdr=[{width="7",alignment="-1",col_name="number",colhdr="Num"},{width="14",alignment="-1",col_name="type",colhdr="Type"},{width="4",alignment="-1",col_name="disp",colhdr="Disp"},{width="3",alignment="-1",col_name="enabled",colhdr="Enb"},{width="10",alignment="-1",col_name="addr",colhdr="Address"},{width="40",alignment="2",col_name="what",colhdr="What"}],body=[]}
>
> (gdb)
>
> 11^done,threads=[]
>
> (gdb)
>
> 12^done,BreakpointTable={nr_rows="0",nr_cols="6",hdr=[{width="7",alignment="-1",col_name="number",colhdr="Num"},{width="14",alignment="-1",col_name="type",colhdr="Type"},{width="4",alignment="-1",col_name="disp",colhdr="Disp"},{width="3",alignment="-1",col_name="enabled",colhdr="Enb"},{width="10",alignment="-1",col_name="addr",colhdr="Address"},{width="40",alignment="2",col_name="what",colhdr="What"}],body=[]}
>
> (gdb)

Note that I successfully enter gdb in Docker, since GDB says:

> "GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-114.el7\n"

In my host operating system (Debian):
`gdb --version`
outputs:

> GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1

In Debian, I execute the Docker command:
`docker-compose -f ~/docker-services/dev/docker-compose.yml exec dev_rhel7 bash -c "gdb -i=mi"`
 and I get the machine-oriented text interface.

From the previous test I deduce that it is an issue of emacs, not Docker.

When entering the path of a binary instead of the option -i=mi, it reads the symbols just fine:
`M-x gdb RETURN docker-compose -f ~/docker-services/dev/docker-compose.yml exec dev_rhel7 bash -c "gdb ~/babel_sandbox/build/foo"`
which outputs:

> Current directory is /home/drcoeurjoly/docker-services/dev/
>
> Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line!
>
> WARNING: The MY_UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>
> 1-inferior-tty-set /dev/pts/3
>
> 2-gdb-set height 0
>
> 3-gdb-set non-stop 1
>
> 4-enable-pretty-printing
>
> 5-file-list-exec-source-files
>
> 6-file-list-exec-source-file
>
> 7-gdb-show prompt
>
> 8-stack-info-frame
>
> 9-thread-info
>
> 10-break-list
>
> 11-thread-info
>
> 12-break-list
>
> GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-114.el7
>
> Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
>
> and "show warranty" for details.
>
> This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
>
> For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>
> http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/...
>
> Reading symbols from /home/drcoeurjoly/babel_sandbox/build/foo...done.
>
> (gdb) 1-inferior-tty-set /dev/pts/3
>
> Undefined command: "1-inferior-tty-set".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 2-gdb-set height 0
>
> Undefined command: "2-gdb-set".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 3-gdb-set non-stop 1
>
> Undefined command: "3-gdb-set".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 4-enable-pretty-printing
>
> Undefined command: "4-enable-pretty-printing".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 5-file-list-exec-source-files
>
> Undefined command: "5-file-list-exec-source-files".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 6-file-list-exec-source-file
>
> Undefined command: "6-file-list-exec-source-file".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 7-gdb-show prompt
>
> Undefined command: "7-gdb-show".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 8-stack-info-frame
>
> Undefined command: "8-stack-info-frame".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 9-thread-info
>
> Undefined command: "9-thread-info".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 10-break-list
>
> Undefined command: "10-break-list".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 11-thread-info
>
> Undefined command: "11-thread-info".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb) 12-break-list
>
> Undefined command: "12-break-list".  Try "help".
>
> (gdb)

I also tried putting the `gdb -i=mi` inside a script and calling that from emacs, to no avail. Calling directly from bash worked and not from emacs.

Relevant information:

- [My spacemacs config](https://github.com/RCoeurjoly/dotfiles)
- [foo program](https://github.com/RCoeurjoly/babel_sandbox/) used for testing argument passing to gdb in emacs.

I don't know if the dockerfile and docker-compose yml are relevant. If so, I will create a repo.

Versions:

Host:
`uname -a`

> Linux des26 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Emacs in host:
`emacs --version`

> GNU Emacs 26.3

GDB in host:
`gdb --version`

> GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1

Docker in host:
`docker --version`

> Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

Docker-compose in host:
`docker-compose --version`

> docker-compose version 1.21.0, build unknown

Docker container:
`cat /etc/redhat-release`

> CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

GDB in docker container:
`gdb --version`

> GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-114.el7

This issue was reported by  Robert Mecklenburg [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-08/msg01216.html) and [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/emacs-gud-mode-fails-with-docker-gdb/37452) as early as august 2017.

Comment: That is indeed some weird behavior.  It smells like a quoting issue, even though you proved that gdb is getting extra arguments in docker.  Maybe try creating a script that does something like `gdb -i=mi "$@"` and invoke that instead of gdb?

Comment: @jpkotta I also tried that, but without the "$@". It didn't work. I have added that experiment to the question. What difference do you think the $@ would make?

Comment: `"$@"` means "all arguments to the script, individually quoted" (c.f. `$@` without the double quotes).  So if `gdb-script` had `gdb -i=mi "$@"`, then `bash -c "gdb-script foo bar"` would run `gdb -i=mi "foo" "bar"`.  The quoting comes in handy if your files have spaces in the name.  But if it still didn't see `-i=mi` when called from the script, it's all moot.  Super weird.

Comment: Maybe you could have a `.gdbinit` file and use something like `new-ui` (https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Interpreters.html#Interpreters).

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not sure that I can do that. It seems that that option cannot be set in gdbinit, but only as a terminal argument